# Are the capabilities python list slicing really asymmetric?

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice, symmetry

Consider the following code:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
>>>   print a[0:i]

[]
[0]
[0, 1]
```

However, when I flip the code to take slices from the other end of the list, it no longer works:

```
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
>>>   print a[-i:]

[0, 1, 2]
[2]
[1, 2]
```

The only way to make the second piece of code to work seems to be to reverse the list, do it the first way, and reverse each piece before printing it. Is there a better way to do this? I use this type of loop sometimes and I would like my code to be as clean as possible.

EDIT: In both loops, I am iterating from left to right. If I flip the direction of iteration as well for the second loop, it works. If I flip the direction of iteration for the first loop, it also has the same hiccup as the second loop:

```
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
>>>   print a[i-1::-1]

[2, 1, 0]
[0]
[1, 0]
```

Answer (score 8):

The first iteration, you are slicing as `-0`, which is just the same as slicing from `0`. Only the second iteration do you slice as `-1`, then `-2`.

Perhaps you could use a range starting at a negative index:

```
for i in range(-len(a), 0):
    print a[-i:]
```

Comment: Arg -- When did you show up here?  Now how am I supposed to FGITW anything?  (+1 btw)

Comment: He hides in the shadows. xD

Answer (score 0):

Reversed slicing cannot be fully symmetric in Python because of 0-based-indexing. Specifically, it isn't possible to distinguish -0 from 0. But the symmetrical access use-case in 0-based-indexed arrays would dictate that if the 0th item is first from the left, then the -0th item (that is, negative 0) is the first from the right, but since 0 and -0 are the same entity, this poses a problem.

Consider the two orientations of a list's indices:

**Forward:** first item is at position 0, second item at position 1, ..., last item at position n-1

**Backward:** first item is at position -1, second at -2, ..., last item at position -n

The negative index notation is therefore a *shorthand* for (length-index): `collection[-i] == collection[len(collection) - i]`

Or, side by side, the indexing is:

```
[0, 1, 2,...,n-1]
[-n,..., -3, -2, -1 ]
```

Where both of the above indices are in fact identical.

To perform a symmetrical operation, your slice operator needs to correctly account for this indexing scheme:

**original slice**: `a[0:i]` == i elements from left end (at 0) with step size of 1 == `a[0:i:1]`

**reverse slice**: i elements from right end (at -1) with step size of *-1*.

Thus, the correct slice from the other end would be `a[-1:-1-i:-1]`

Note that the stop value here is the negative of i, offset by -1 to account for the -1-based-reversed-indexing, which is necessary as we are generating i using a forward based list (e.g. the range function.)

```
a = range(3) # [0,1,2]
for i in range(len(a)):
    # forward case, next to backward case
    print a[:i], a[-1:-1-i:-1]
# [] []
# [0] [2]
# [0, 1] [2, 1]
```